# What process does QGIS use when re-exporting rasters to a lower resolution?

Tags: qgis, raster, resolution

I've been re-exporting some 300m-resolution rasters in QGIS to 1000m resolution. I first re-export the rasters to EPSG:5880 so that the units would be in meters, then I re-export the raster to 1000m (by right-clicking on the layer and clicking Export). My supervisor wants to know what exactly happens under the hood when I reduce the raster resolution like that. Does anyone know what process is used, e.g. does QGIS take the average of 300m pixel values in each 1000m square? Could you link a source, too?

Comment: Nearest neighbour - [What resampling method is used in the raster 'Save as...' dialog?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223799/what-resampling-method-is-used-in-the-raster-save-as-dialog). If you want to use a different resampling method, use the GDAL -> Raster conversion -> Translate tool and add a -r {nearest,bilinear,cubic,cubicspline,lanczos,average,rms,mode} additional command-line parameter (the Translate tool uses [`gdal_translate`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html) behind the scenes).